# Display output in a tabbed window

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have developed a task manager for Linux in Java. The output as of now is displayed in the console whereas a tabbed window appears separately (this was done using Java Swing). 
Now I want the output from the console to be displayed in the tabbed window.

How do I do it?

There are classes that I've used. One for the task manager functionality and the other for GUI. I've pasted below the coding.

```
**TabbedPaneDemo1.java**

package components;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;


/*
 * TabbedPaneDemo.java requires one additional file:
 *   images/middle.gif.
 */

import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class TabbedPaneDemo1
{

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    try
    {   
        TextArea textarea = new TextArea();
        TabbedPaneDemo obj = new TabbedPaneDemo();
        obj.fn();
        String line;
        String result = "";
        FileOutputStream out;
        //FileOutputStream out; // declare a file output object
        PrintStream p;
        Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe");
        out = new FileOutputStream("myfile.txt");//write to a file//
        p = new PrintStream( out );
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p1.getInputStream()));//read form a file//
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
            //textarea.append(line + "\n");
            result += line+"\n";
            p.println (line);
            //textarea.setVisible(true);    
        }
        //msgBox(result);
        p.close();
        input.close();   
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}
    public static void msgBox(String msg) {
    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog((java.awt.Component)
    null, msg, "WindowsUtils",
    javax.swing.JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
    }
}

**TabbedPaneDemo.java**

package components;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class TabbedPaneDemo extends JPanel {
Integer i;
public TabbedPaneDemo() {
    super(new GridLayout(1, 1));

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images");


    JComponent panel1 = makeTextPanel("tasklist");
    tabbedPane.addTab("tasks", icon, panel1,
            "ta");
    tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);

    JComponent panel2 = makeTextPanel("windows");
    tabbedPane.addTab("wins", icon, panel2,
            "wi");
    tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(1, KeyEvent.VK_2);


    add(tabbedPane);`enter code here`
        tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);    
    }
    protected JComponent makeTextPanel(String text)
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);
        JLabel filler = new JLabel(text);
        filler.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        panel.add(filler);
        return panel;
    }
    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = TabbedPaneDemo.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TabbedPaneDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TabbedPaneDemo(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void fn() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
        createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very naive implementation of it.

```
package test.t100.t001;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TabbedPaneDemo extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Integer i;

    JTextArea output = new JTextArea();

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("TabbedPaneDemo");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TabbedPaneDemo(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private String getDetails() throws IOException {
        //fn();
        String line;
        String result = "";
        PrintStream p;
        Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe");
        // read from a process
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p1.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
        {
            //System.out.println(line);
            output.append(line + "\n");
            result += line+"\n";
            //p.println (line);
            //textarea.setVisible(true);    
        }
        //msgBox(result);
        //p.close();
        input.close();   

        return result;
    }

    public TabbedPaneDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1, 1));

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images");


        JComponent panel1 = makeTextPanel("tasklist");
        tabbedPane.addTab("tasks", icon, panel1,
                "ta");
        // add it to something!
        panel1.add(new JScrollPane(output));
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);

        JComponent panel2 = makeTextPanel("windows");
        tabbedPane.addTab("wins", icon, panel2,
                "wi");
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(1, KeyEvent.VK_2);


        add(tabbedPane);//`enter code here`
        tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);

        try {
            String s = getDetails();
            output.setText(s);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void msgBox(String msg) {
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog((java.awt.Component)
                null, msg, "WindowsUtils",
                javax.swing.JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
    }


    protected JComponent makeTextPanel(String text)
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);
        JLabel filler = new JLabel(text);
        filler.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        panel.add(filler);
        return panel;
    }

    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = TabbedPaneDemo.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

### Other notes:

1. For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Especially don't include unnecessary images.
2. Use a `JTable` for this type of data.
3. The code dumps the text area in a tabbed pane that apparently has a `GridLayout` - BNI
4. Don't mix Swing & AWT components without good reason.
5. As already mentioned, use a `SwingWorker` for getting the data.

### Update

> ..but the output from the console doesn't appear.

Uh-huh.  Let's think about

> I have developed a task manager for **Linux** in Java

..combined with..

```
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe");
```

Now, correct me if I misunderstand something, but AFIAU **Linux has no EXEs.**

I'm guessing the code fails on Linux, and since the `err` stream of the process is being ignored, you are not being told why.  Here is a screen-shot of the code shown above, as it appears on **Windows** 7.

[image: Working output in tabbed pane]

Now, if the data had been hard-coded, you might be seeing something like above.  Which answers the stated question of "(How to) Display output in a tabbed window", right?

More info. on the *new* problem you are seeing is to be had by implementing all the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  If you implement all the suggestions & still cannot figure the problem, I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: Thnx Andrew.. But the output from the console doesn't appear. I had the same problem previously too. Can you guide me pls as to how to get the output onto the tabbed window.

Comment: See the **Update** to answer.

Comment: I am using tasklist.exe in java eclipse under windows platform. One done, I will use "ps-ef" or "ps-aux" in java o get the output. But the correct linkage from the console to the panewindow doesn't happen. I am stuck there

Comment: How does the source I provided behave on your Windows machine?  Have you read & implemented **all** of the recommendations of the linked article on `exec()`?

Comment: It still remains the same. I have seriously lost track. The output in the concole also doesn't appear.

Comment: @Thompson: Yes, i have got it... Thnx much. Will continue from here. :)

Comment: @Thompson: The coding that you helped me with, works fine on windows platform but not on Linux platform. I gave ~ Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps"); ~ instead of "tasklist.exe"... Why is isn't it working. What should I do?

Comment: That code I posted **does not implement** all the recommendations of the linked article.  I think you should start a new question and try it in the command line (no GUI) first.  But make sure you take care of the typical traps first.

Comment: @Thompson: Okie:) Thnx... Will do

Answer (score 2):

only points

- `TextArea textarea = new TextArea();` why AWT Component

  use Swing `JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea();`

you can load data to the `JTextArea` directly from

- `FileOutputStream` from `Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime()`

or read from `File`

- `JTextArea.read(File)` accepting `"\n"`

or from `FileReader` or `FileXxxx` e.i.

- `JTextArea.append(String)`

you have issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and you have to call/ to redirect

```
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime()
```

and

```
FileIO
```

to the Background task, there are

- by invoke from `Runnable#Thread` (output to the `JTextArea` should be wrapped into `invokeLater`)

or

- use `SwingWorker` (output from `process` or `publish` could be done on `Event Dispatch Thread`)